# If JWT and baseurl can be copied from the network tab, can't anyone access the information in the postman?

Tags: reactjs, security, jwt, csrf

Lets say I have a react app and there is an API for login which sends a JWT token in the response. I log in and by using that token, an API is called to see all my bookings.

Now my confusion comes here. If I go to network tab, I can see the JWT token and request URL in the network tab. Now if I take the JWT and baseurl and go to postman, I can see my booking.

Since we can not restrict the browser to show the API calls that are being made, it means if I am logged in and say anyone like some sort of hacker get the token and baseurl, they would be able to access and alter my profile or even get more deep into the server and database (may be, I am not quite sure of all the hacking).

I have seen many articles, questions and resources which explains how if JWT is altered than the signature won't match. Lets not alter the JWT. And also JWT have expiration time. Ok but what if the JWT still has some time to expire.

Lets say it is not for getting bookings but for editing my profile. And hacker gets the token from headers and base URL. It would mean that I am dead now. He can do whatever he likes.

So what I am concerned is how to make the API call more secure? What are the best practices and how to secure the API calls (mostly in react and node at the backend)?

Comment: `say anyone like some sort of hacker get the token and baseurl, they would be able to access and alter my profile` So don't let them get your token. This isn't specific to JWT, your username and password is visible in the network tab aswell. `or even get more deep into the server and database` Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @tkausl For this: So don't let them get your token. 
That is the issue. How to do that? 
For this: or even get more deep into the server and database
I am just saying they access any other information from the server.

Answer (score -1):

Short Token Expiry: Set short expiration times for your tokens, including access tokens and refresh tokens. Short-lived tokens limit the window of opportunity for an attacker to use a stolen token.

Token Rotation and Refresh: Implement token rotation and refresh mechanisms. Periodically rotate tokens to invalidate previous tokens. This can be done by issuing new tokens and invalidating the old ones.

Use HTTP-only Cookies: When using cookies for token storage, set them as HTTP-only. This prevents client-side scripts, including malicious scripts injected through XSS attacks, from accessing the token.

CORS and Same-Origin Policy: Implement proper Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policies on the server to control which domains can make requests to your API. Additionally, adhere to the same-origin policy to prevent unauthorized domains from accessing sensitive information.

Above are suggestions and not foolproof solutions for postmen tool blocking.